# Check if a particular ID exists in another table or not using MySQL join

Tags: mysql

I have two SQL tables, and I like to have the result shown below.

**table_1**

```
id      userId
---------------
1           u1
2           u2
3           u3
4           u4
5           u5
```

**table_2**

```
userId      flag
-----------------
u1          1
u4          0
```

**Result I need**

```
id      userId      flag
------------------------
1           u1      1
2           u2      Null
3           u3      Null
4           u4      0
5           u5      Null
```

Comment: Hint: outer join will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this following  LEFT JOIN for the purpose, It will give all right table data with matched right table data
.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 on table_1.userId=table_2.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

use the left outer join:

```
select table_1.id, table_1.userid, table_2.flag 
from table_1 
  left outer join table_2 on table_1.userid=table_2.userid
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `left join` and `Left Outer Join` ?

Comment: @Sadikhasan no not as i know

Comment: @Sadikhasan, those are syntactic sugar and nothing more than that. `left join` is shorter form of `left outer join`. Few RDBMS even go in shortening it further.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for Guide me

Answer (score 0):

you can use join or Under-expression
for join :

```
select 
t1.id,
t1.userid,
t2.flag  
from table_1  t1
inner join table_2 t2
on t1.userid = t2.userid
```

under-expression

```
select 
t1.id,
t1.userid,
(select flag from table_2 t2 WHERE t1.userid=t2.userid) as flag
from table_1  t1
```